# Rails Paginate Issue with Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I'm having this problem I can't seem to wrap my head around it...
Basically, I installed a gem (kaminari) that is supposed to solve the problem of pagination on my blog site - the problem appears when I use the .per method in the controllers, I get an error, but when I don't use it, there is no pagination on the site, although I can move around in the browser by typing the parameters for the page such as ?page=2,

Showing /home/mehmed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views/kaminari/_paginator.html.erb where line #14 raised:

unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash

Controller:

```
def index
    @blogs = Blog.all.order("id DESC").page(params[:page]).per(5)
end
```

View:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
   <%= render @blogs %>
   <%= paginate @blogs %>
</div>
```

Model:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
    enum status: {draft: 0, published: 1}
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

    validates_presence_of :title, :body
    belongs_to :topic
end
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `Blog.all.order("id DESC").page(params[:page]).per(5)` as opposed to `Blog.paginate(("id DESC").page: params[:page] per_page: 5)`

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I fixed it to use kaminari **latest version**, *not kaminari 0.16.3*.

Comment: Please be more descriptive. like which version?

Comment: 1) I used  kaminari 1.1.1.
2)I had same code (because it from online course Devcamp), and same problem. I **fixed it**, when changed kaminari version from 0.16.3 to 1.1.1. I decided to share solution.

Comment: And generally the first step in solving someone's question is to reproduce the issue, so ideally everyone posting an answer would have the same problem before solving it. You can leave that part out of your future answers, to avoid quick-trigger moderators.